# Display Row value as column after grouping- Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

Here is my Query

```
SELECT
  tbl_dtl_feature.customer_id,
  result,
  COUNT(*) AS expr1
FROM tbl_dtl_feature
WHERE tbl_dtl_feature.feature_id = 'F001'
      AND TRUNC(tbl_dtl_feature.start_datetime)
      BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY tbl_dtl_feature.result, tbl_dtl_feature.customer_id
```

My Result set:

```
CustomerID  Result  Count
----------  ------- -----
44438111    Success 3
44438444    Success 1
44438111    Failure 1
```

Expected Result Set:

```
CustomerID  Count(Success) Count(Failure)
----------  -------------- -------------
44438111       3              1
44438444       1              0
```

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT t.customer_id, 
       count(CASE WHEN result = 'Success' THEN 1 END) Count_Success, 
       count(CASE WHEN result = 'Failure' THEN 1 END) Count_Failure
FROM   tbl_dtl_feature t
WHERE  t.feature_id = 'F001'
AND    trunc(t.start_datetime) BETWEEN to_date('10/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('10/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
GROUP BY t.customer_id;
```